# Java code working on InventoryPart 2 program, have no idea what I am doing wrong?

Tags: java

I get the following error code:

> C:\Documents and Settings\AdminUser\My Documents\InventoryPart2.java:83: class, interface, or enum expected
>   import java.util.*;
>   ^
>   1 error
>
> Tool completed with exit code 1

when compiling these source files:

```
public class Television { //class name and attributes

    private String ItemNumber; //item # of product
    private String ProductName; //product name
    private double UnitsStock; //# of units in stock
    private double UnitPrice; //Price per unit
    private double InventoryValue; //The dollar value of the inventory in stock
    private double CalculateInventory; //The total value of all of the inventory in stock
    private double value;

    //constructor
    public Television (String item, String product, double units, double price) {
        ItemNumber = item;
        ProductName = product;
        UnitsStock = units;
        UnitPrice = price;
    } //end constructor

    //getter and setter methods for Television

    public void setItemNumber (String item) { //setter for item number
        this.ItemNumber = item;
    } //end setter item number

    public String getItemNumber() { //getter for item number
        return ItemNumber;
    } //end getter item number

    public void setProductName (String product) { //setter for product name
        this.ProductName = product;
    } //end setter product name

    public String getProductName() { //getter for product name
        return ProductName;
    } //end getter product name

    public void setUnitsStock (double units) { //setter for units in stock
        this.UnitsStock = units;
    } //end setter units in stock

    public double getUnitsStock() { //getter for units in stock
        return UnitsStock;
    } //end getter units in stock

    public void setUnitPrice (double price) { //setter for unit price
        this.UnitPrice = price;
    } //end setter unit price

    public double getUnitPrice() { //getter for unit price
        return UnitPrice;
    } //end getter for unit price

    //calculate inventory value
    public double getInventoryValue(){
        return UnitsStock * UnitPrice;
    }//end calculate inventory value

    public void setCalculateInventory (double value){
        this.CalculateInventory = value;
    }

    public double getCalculateInventory(){
        double value = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            value = getInventoryValue();
        }
        return value;
    }
    //end getter and setter methods for Television
} //end class Television
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InventoryPart2 {

    public static void main (String args []){

        //instantiate Television array

        Television myTelevisions[] = new Television[5];

        myTelevisions[0] = new Television ("0001", " Samsung UN46D6400",9,1599.99);
        myTelevisions[1] = new Television ("0002", " Vizio XVT553SV",6,1299.00);
        myTelevisions[2] = new Television ("0003", " Panasonic Viera TC-P50VT25",2,2079.99);
        myTelevisions[3] = new Television ("0004", " Sony Bravia KDL-55EX720",8, 1889.99);
        myTelevisions[4] = new Television ("0005", " LG Infinia 47LX9500",2,2099.00);

        //output
        for (int i = 0; i < myTelevisions.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Product Number: \t\t" + myTelevisions[i].getItemNumber());
            System.out.println("Product Name: \t\t\t" + myTelevisions[i].getProductName());
            System.out.println("Number of Units in Stock: \t" + myTelevisions[i].getUnitsStock());
            System.out.printf("Price per Unit: \t\t$%.2f\n", + myTelevisions[i].getUnitPrice());
            System.out.printf("Value of Inventory: \t\t$%.2f\n", + myTelevisions[i].getInventoryValue());
            System.out.println();
        } // end output

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //output total inventory value
            System.out.printf("Total Value of Inventory is: \t$%.2f\n", + myTelevision[i].getCalculateInventory());
            System.out.println();
        }//end output total inventory value
    } //end method main
} //end class InventoryPart1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Greg and @EboMike stated, make sure you split your code in two files: *Television.java* and *InventoryPart2.java*.

Then, you have a typo here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //output total inventory value
    System.out.printf("Total Value of Inventory is: \t$%.2f\n", + myTelevision[i].getCalculateInventory());
    System.out.println();
}
```

It's myTelevision **s**[i].

If you fix what I'm telling you, your code runs fine... no worries. :)

**EDIT:**

I shouldn't be checking your code's logic here but if the last cycle is meant to compute the total inventory sum it should be something like this:

```
    //output total inventory value
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
        total +=  myTelevisions[i].getCalculateInventory();            
    }
    System.out.printf("Total Value of Inventory is: \t$%.2f\n", total);
```

Comment: I thank all of you the code is working prefectly. All of you are the best all you r help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the same file? The import statement needs to go to the top.

The error message clearly shows you which line is causing a problem.

Comment: I do not understand. So frustrated can not get this right, have no problem with my other class working with JavaScript. I am totally confused.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript? Java and JavaScript are not related. And what's not to understand about the requirement that `import` needs to come before your class declarations?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a line

```
import java.util.*;
```

in the middle of your file. Java requires that `import` declarations go at the *top* of the file, before any `class`, `interface`, or `enum` declarations.

Comment: I do not want to sound like a total idiot but I really do not understand any of this. I have had only one code work properly this whole class, have 2 more weeks of this. Instructor is not helping, this is 1 of 2 classes to get my degree.

Comment: @Raven50, please don't edit answers to include error messages; instead, either include them as _comments_ here, or, if they would look much better with formatting, by editing your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems jump out at me:

1. As the error message says, you have an import statement out of place. Imports go at the top, after the package declaration and before the class declaration.
2. Assuming that the code you posted is in fact all in one file, you need to separate it into two files. You can't have two public classes in one .java file.